# Find float column max scale and precision

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I have a column with datatype float in Teradata. I want to find the Maximum precision and scale for that column.

Note: My column's scale part has more than 10 digits in most of the places.

Sample Data

```
123.12321323002
13123213.13200003
33232.213123001
```

The output I need is
Precsion 19 (scale + length of 13123213) and scale is 11 (length of 12321323002)
or

8 (length of 13123213), 11 (length of 12321323002).

I tried to find them buy converting the column as varchar and splitting them based on the '.' and make the integer and fractional part as 2 columns and then finding the max length of 2 columns. But when I'm select the data, Teradata rounds off the scale part. So after that, if I convert them as char, I'm getting lesser value for scale part.

For example:

org data: 1234.12312000123101

data when I select from Teradata: 1234.12312000123

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Teradata uses the IEEE format for real/float values.  This gives 15-17 digits of precision.  Alas, you need 19 digits, so **the values you want are not being stored in the database**.  You cannot recover them.

What you can do is fix the database, so it uses `numeric`/`decimal`/`number`.  This supports what you want:  `NUMERIC(19, 11)`.  You would then need to reload the data so it is correctly stored in the database.

Comment: TL;DR - never use float, the problems outweigh any possible benefits.

Comment: @Andrew . . . Floats have a place when the *range* of values exceeds anything that could be represented in a fixed-length format.  In real world databases, that is very, very rarely needed.  In business databases, perhaps never.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just can't stand the un-predictability, lack of guaranteed accuracy with floats.  But maybe that's just because I'm a little OCD...

Answer (score 0):

When you need high precision without predefined scale simply switch to the `NUMBER` datatype, which is a mixture of DECIMAL and FLOAT.

Exact numeric, at least 38 digits precision, no predefined scale, range of 1E-130 .. 1E125.

Float on steroids :-)